# How to use 256-glyphs font in XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

I know a good font for (La)TeX. This is 256-glyphs non-Unicode LH-fonts.
I use XeTeX with Unicode encoding. There are many chars with codes above 256.
XeTeX currently doesn't know which glyphs are present in such fonts.
How to map these Unicode codes to glyph slot codes between 128 and 255?
I want something like that.

Macro `\glyphcode` does not exist. But I would like

```
\font\lh = larm1000
\glyphcode \lh `\п = 239
\lh п
```

To print "п" by "larm1000"-font XeTeX must use 239 glyph from larm1000 rather than Unicode code.  I know bad workaround

```
\catcode`\п = 13 \def п{\char239 }
```

But I want letters to have 11 catcode.

Comment: You can use such fonts the same way you used them with 8-bit TeX engines.

Comment: Yes, of course. But I want to use `utf8`. I need some chars like `≤ ≥ ∑ ∆ √ ∫ ˚ …`

Comment: You can probably use [`xetex-inputenc`](https://github.com/wspr/xetex-inputenc) for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that character mapping like `mapping=tex-text` cannot be applied to fonts in TFM format, which instead I hoped for. But the `LA` fonts are incorporated in the CMUnicode fonts that are available in TeX Live

Comment: egreg! That's it! CMUnicode.

Answer (score 2):

You can't apply `mapping=tex-text` or any other mapping to legacy TFM fonts in XeTeX (while those fonts can still be used in the traditional way also with XeTeX).

There are OpenType clones of the Computer Modern fonts that include also Cyrillic glyphs, issued by the [CM-Unicode project](http://canopus.iacp.dvo.ru/~panov/cm-unicode/), present also on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cm-unicode) and included in TeX Live.

So

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CMU Serif}
```

should be what you need. The font file name is `cmunrm.otf` if you need to call it in this way.

Comment: For me it shown an error with name "CMU Serif". When I changed the name to "cmunrm.otf, it worked.

Comment: @user4035 are you on Mac OS? XeTeX by default does not see the fonts provided by TeXLive, except if you use filenames.

Comment: @jfbu It's easy to copy the font files to `/Library/Fonts`.

Comment: That is indeed the simplest way. Personally I use symlinks to `texmf-dist/fonts/opentype` and `texmf-dist/fonts/truetype` from `~/Library/Fonts` but I have to open the FontBook from time to time to let it update its database when TeXLive updates things (or so I think).

Comment: @jfbu No, on Linux Slackware 14.2, TexLive 2016.

Comment: @user4035 I can't try this out, can only confirm that it works with `CMU Serif` on Mac OS X with TeXLive 2016 with my symlinks, and surely would work if I copied the font to a location the system knows about as suggested by egreg.